# django url email argument doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass an email trough a URL and I'm receiving this error:

> The current URL, fback/test@gmail.com/, didn't match any of these.

my `urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import *

urlpatterns = patterns('fback.views',

url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
url(r'^fback/(?P<email>\t+)/$', 'vedi_dettagli', name='vedi'),
#url(r'^fback/dettagli', 'vedi_dettagli', name='vedialtro'),

)
```

the `views.py` is:

```
def vedi_dettagli(request, email):
vedi = get_object_or_404(Societa, email='email')
response = render_to_response('fback/dettagli.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
return response
```

Can anybody see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
url(r'^fback/(?P<email>\w+)/$', 'vedi_dettagli', name='vedi'),
```

also:

```
def vedi_dettagli(request, email):
    vedi = get_object_or_404(Societa, email=email) ####<< not 'email'
    response = render_to_response('fback/dettagli.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))
    return response
```